# Disable auto resizing of windows when dragged to the top and/or screen edges

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I've been using GNOME (in **Arch Linux**) for a while. There is something that really bothers me (that I used to disable in Ubuntu) and it's the capability to:

- Maximize windows when dragging to the top of the screen
- Fill to the half the screen when dragging to the side(s)

See **Resizing Windows** [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Gnome3CheatSheet).

Is there any way to disable that in GNOME `3.28.0`?

> The answers related with the change on `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.classic-overrides edge-tiling` to `false` don't work for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling false
```

You may also have to run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides edge-tiling false
```

Comment: That did the trick!

Answer (score 4):

This setting is native now on `GNOME` — it's under `Settings` > `Multitasking`.

---

<s>Alternatively, if `GNOME Tweaks` is installed, going to `Windows` there is an option named `Edge Tiling`...just disable it ― the result is the same.</s>

Comment: There is no option named "Edge Tiling" in GNOME Tweaks -> Windows on Ubuntu